# Insert one column from one DB to Another DB

Tags: insert, oracle-sqldeveloper

i'm having two DB (DB1 & DB2) in oracle SQL developer.I need to copy a column of DB1.table1 to the table of DB2.table2.
I tried many times but its not working

INSERT INTO database1.table1
(
  column1,column2
)SELECT (column1,column2) FROM database2.table2

please help. I want to insert only one row at a time.

Answer (score 2):

If you have db link then you can do in following manner

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1,column2 )
SELECT (column1,column2) FROM table2@dblink
```

for eg:
I have two database db1 and db2, db link between them is ipdb and i have to copy the column from db1 table to db2 table.

```
INSERT INTO table2 ( column1,column2 )
SELECT (column1,column2) FROM table1@dblink
```

`table1` is in db1 and `table2` is in db2